# Issues with midi file in Java

Tags: java, swing, audio, midi

i'm reading a java programming book, and they show this example:

```
// chapter 14

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class BeatBox {  // implements MetaEventListener 

      JPanel mainPanel;
      ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxList;
      // int bpm = 120;
      Sequencer sequencer;
      Sequence sequence;
      Sequence mySequence = null;
      Track track;
      JFrame theFrame;

      String[] instrumentNames = {"Bass Drum", "Closed Hi-Hat", 
         "Open Hi-Hat","Acoustic Snare", "Crash Cymbal", "Hand Clap", 
         "High Tom", "Hi Bongo", "Maracas", "Whistle", "Low Conga", 
         "Cowbell", "Vibraslap", "Low-mid Tom", "High Agogo", 
         "Open Hi Conga"};
      int[] instruments = {35,42,46,38,49,39,50,60,70,72,64,56,58,47,67,63};


      public static void main (String[] args) {
        new BeatBox().buildGUI();
      }

      public void buildGUI() {
          theFrame = new JFrame("Cyber BeatBox");
          theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
          JPanel background = new JPanel(layout);
          background.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

          checkboxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
          Box buttonBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

          JButton start = new JButton("Start");
          start.addActionListener(new MyStartListener());
          buttonBox.add(start);


          JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
          stop.addActionListener(new MyStopListener());
          buttonBox.add(stop);

          JButton upTempo = new JButton("Tempo Up");
          upTempo.addActionListener(new MyUpTempoListener());
          buttonBox.add(upTempo);

           JButton downTempo = new JButton("Tempo Down");
          downTempo.addActionListener(new MyDownTempoListener());
          buttonBox.add(downTempo);

          JButton saveIt = new JButton("Serialize It");  // new button
          saveIt.addActionListener(new MySendListener());
          buttonBox.add(saveIt);

          JButton restore = new JButton("Restore");     // new button
          restore.addActionListener(new MyReadInListener());
          buttonBox.add(restore);

          Box nameBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
          for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
              nameBox.add(new Label(instrumentNames[i]));
          }

          background.add(BorderLayout.EAST, buttonBox);
          background.add(BorderLayout.WEST, nameBox);

          theFrame.getContentPane().add(background);

          GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(16,16);
          grid.setVgap(1);
          grid.setHgap(2);
          mainPanel = new JPanel(grid);
          background.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);


          for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {                    
                JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();
                c.setSelected(false);
                checkboxList.add(c);
                mainPanel.add(c);            
          } // end loop

          setUpMidi();

          theFrame.setBounds(50,50,300,300);
          theFrame.pack();
          theFrame.setVisible(true);
        } // close method


     public void setUpMidi() {
       try {
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        // sequencer.addMetaEventListener(this);
        sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
        track = sequence.createTrack();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);

       } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } // close method
/*
     public class MyCheckBoxListener implements ItemListener {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {      
           // might add real-time removal or addition, probably not because of timing
        }
     } // close inner class
*/

     public void buildTrackAndStart() {
        // this will hold the instruments for each vertical column,
        // in other words, each tick (may have multiple instruments)
        int[] trackList = null;

        sequence.deleteTrack(track);
        track = sequence.createTrack();


      for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
         trackList = new int[16];

         int key = instruments[i];

         for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++ ) {         
               JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j + (16*i));

              if ( jc.isSelected()) {
                 trackList[j] = key;
              } else {
                 trackList[j] = 0;
              }       
          } // close inner

       makeTracks(trackList);
     } // close outer

     track.add(makeEvent(192,9,1,0,15)); // - so we always go to full 16 beats 



       try {

           sequencer.setSequence(sequence);  
           sequencer.setLoopCount(sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);                  
           sequencer.start();
           sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
       } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

      } // close method

//============================================================== inner class listeners           

      public class MyStartListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
             buildTrackAndStart();
         }
      }

    public class MyStopListener implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
           sequencer.stop();
       }
    }

    public class MyUpTempoListener implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
            sequencer.setTempoFactor((float)(tempoFactor * 1.03));
       }
    }

    public class MyDownTempoListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            float tempoFactor = sequencer.getTempoFactor();
            sequencer.setTempoFactor((float)(tempoFactor * .97));
        }
    }

    public class MySendListener implements ActionListener {    // new - save
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
          // make an arraylist of just the STATE of the checkboxes
         boolean[] checkboxState = new boolean[256];

         for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
             JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
             if (check.isSelected()) {
                checkboxState[i] = true;
             }
          }

         try {
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("Checkbox.ser"));
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            os.writeObject(checkboxState);
         } catch(Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }

       } // close method
     } // close inner class



    public class MyReadInListener implements ActionListener {  // new - restore
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
          // read in the thing

          boolean[] checkboxState = null;
          try {
              FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(
                  new File("Checkbox.ser"));
              ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
              checkboxState = (boolean[]) is.readObject();

          } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

              // now reset the sequence to be this
          for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
             JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
             if (checkboxState[i]) {
                check.setSelected(true);
             } else {
                check.setSelected(false);
             }
         } 



        // now stop sequence and restart
        sequencer.stop(); 
        buildTrackAndStart();
      } // close method
  } // close inner class


//==============================================================       

     public void makeTracks(int[] list) {

         for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
           int key = list[i];

           if (key != 0) {
               track.add(makeEvent(144,9,key, 100, i));
               track.add(makeEvent(128,9,key, 100, i + 1));
           }
         }
      }



     public  MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {
          MidiEvent event = null;
          try {
            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
            event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);

            }catch(Exception e) { }
          return event;
       }

/*
        public void meta(MetaMessage message) {
            if (message.getType() == 47) {
                sequencer.start();
                sequencer.setTempoInBPM(bpm);
            }
       }
*/


   } // close class
```

It's a simple beatboc machine, but i can't figure out why on my pc is seems to be broken. If i try to compile the code, the first 3/4 rows work properly, but the other make allt he same sound.... especially maracas, hi bongo, whistle...

For other users online seems to work fine, what could be the problem? i've also installed in the /lib/audio the deluxe soundbank, but nothing has changed.

Comment: My guess would be the MIDI sound capabilities of your sound card. Given most people don't use it, ever, the standard MIDI capabilities of most sound cards hasn't improved in many years. My guess is yours only supports 128 sounds, so you get the same noise for multiple different instruments.

Comment: i don't think so... i've a new macbook pro....ai tried it on different pcs and give me the same problem..can you try it on yours?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working through the same programming book (head first Java), which covers up to Java 5.0.

If your using Java 7,   [a new software synthesiser has been implemented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/enhancements_7.html). Which doesn't support the General MIDI soundbank the code is using.

The problem can be fixed by loading a soundbank that follows the GM guidelines into a new synthesiser instance and linking it to an unconnected sequencer. Here's a suitable [soundbank](http://www.ntonyx.com/sf_f.htm). But there's a few different sounding ones around the web.

Here's the code inside the setupMidi() method:

```
public void setUpMidi() {
    try {

        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer(false); // returns unconnected sequencer
        sequencer.open();

        synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer(); // return new synth 
        synth.open();

        soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new File("32MbGMStereo.sf2"));
        synth.loadAllInstruments(soundbank); // load GM soundbank

        Receiver synthReceiver = synth.getReceiver();
        Transmitter seqTransmitter = sequencer.getTransmitter();
        seqTransmitter.setReceiver(synthReceiver); // connect sequencer to synth

        sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
        track = sequence.createTrack();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);

    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code.
Seems everything works at my laptop (HP EliteBook)
At first I had an error, but I found it was because I needed to run Eclipse as Admin.
But I found that solution on the forum that goes with your book, I suppose.
see: http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/88039-windows-regcreatekeyex-returned-error-code-5/

The only thing I noticed, is that if the loop is running, and I check other sounds, it often does not play these sounds until I click the 'start'-button again.
But that's all.

#### EDIT

I've found a somewhat similar topic. Maybe it's any use to you?
[Java Midi in Mac OSX Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148898/java-midi-in-mac-osx-broken)

#### EDIT

For refreshing the pattern, afther every selection, I would suggest a change to your code, like this:

```
 public void buildTrack() {
         // this will hold the instruments for each vertical column,
         // in other words, each tick (may have multiple instruments)
         int[] trackList = null;

         sequence.deleteTrack(track);
         track = sequence.createTrack();


       for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
          trackList = new int[16];

          int key = instruments[i];

          for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++ ) {         
                JCheckBox jc = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(j + (16*i));

               if ( jc.isSelected()) {
                  trackList[j] = key;
               } else {
                  trackList[j] = 0;
               }       
           } // close inner

        makeTracks(trackList);
      } // close outer

      track.add(makeEvent(192,9,1,0,15)); // - so we always go to full 16 beats 



        try {

            sequencer.setSequence(sequence);  

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

       } // close method

  public void buildTrackAndStart() {

    try {

        buildTrack();
        sequencer.setLoopCount(sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);                  
        sequencer.start();
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(120);
    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

   } // close method
```

And then you need to create a CheckBoxListener:

```
public class MyCheckboxListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
         buildTrack();
     }
 }
```

Add it to your checkboxes, by adding this line:

```
c.addActionListener(new MyCheckboxListener());
```

To your 'for' block, just before 'setupMidi()'
like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {                    
             JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();
             c.setSelected(false);
             c.addActionListener(new MyCheckboxListener());
             checkboxList.add(c);
             mainPanel.add(c);            
       } // end loop
```

And that should do the trick!

Comment: first of all ty, second: i've tried to read anything... but the problem is eith the midi package of java.. or it depends on which java version you have. The problem is that i cannot be sure.. the code seems to be right... i don't know what to do