# PLATFORM_API_MacOSX_MidiOut.c: 162->Invalid message:

Tags: java, clock, midi

Hello everyone I have been digging the javax.sound.midi Api and I came across with the issue that I think is not related with the library itself but something related with mac. Well I have this simple code to send a Timing clock midi message. And receive this red message"PLATFORM_API_MacOSX_MidiOut.c: 162->Invalid message: message status=0xF8 while sending short message". Anyone knows  work around this? thank in advance

I had a look at this source code https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/macosx/native/com/sun/media/sound/PLATFORM_API_MacOSX_MidiOut.c
And it seem the range of midi message is a bit constrained.

public class TestMidiLibrary {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MidiDevice.Info[] info = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
    MidiDevice device = null;
    try {
        device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info[6]);
        device.open();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
    try {
        msg.setMessage(ShortMessage.TIMING_CLOCK);
        long timeStamp = -1;
        Receiver r = device.getReceiver();
        r.send(msg,timeStamp);
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException | MidiUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [Here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/macosx-port/macosx-port/jdk/file/65910faed942/src/macosx/native/com/sun/media/sound/PLATFORM_API_MacOSX_MidiOut.c#l126)'s the code raising the error. Seems like it only handles MIDI_TIME_CODE,  SONG_POSITION_POINTER, SONG_SELECT and TUNE_REQUEST for some reason

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148898/java-midi-in-mac-osx-broken)'s another question on the same topic, answers state that the MacOS Java MIDI implementation is half-hearted and provides an alternative library, but that link 404s...

Comment: Aaron yes I read about that library mmi but the link is dead and i couldn't trace any alternative. Thank you ;)

Comment: The site of the editor is still up though, might be worth [contact](https://www.humatic.de/contact.html)ing them if you don't get any answer

Comment: What do you need those messages for?? Create your own messages  It's not too far of a possibility

Comment: Im using the javax.audio.midi. Those are midi messages. I don't know what do you mea?