# MIDI playback via javax.sound.midi.Sequencer pauses intermittently

Tags: java, clojure, midi, javax.sound.midi

I have a short snippet of Clojure code using the `javax.sound.midi` library to play a MIDI file. The problem is that, upon playback, the Sequence frequently pauses playback for about 20-30 seconds, then resumes. Here is the snippet of code:

```
;; given a string representing path to midi file, evaluate to a Sequence object
(defn read-midi-file [s]
  (if (nil? (re-matches #"[^\r\n]+.(mid|midi)" s))
    (throw (InvalidMidiDataException. "Invalid MIDI file."))
    (try
      (MidiSystem/getSequence (java.io.File. s))
      (catch Exception e
        (throw (IOException. "Could not read MIDI file."))))))

;; play the midi sequence back
(defn play-midi-file [mseq]
  (let [sequencer (MidiSystem/getSequencer)]
    (.open sequencer)
    (.setSequence sequencer mseq)
    (.start sequencer)))  ; TODO: add MetaEventListener to determine when to stop

(play-midi-file (read-midi-file "/path/to/file/test.mid"))
```

Just to make sure, I checked the latency of the `javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer` object at the REPL:

```
user> (* 0.001 (.getLatency (javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem/getSynthesizer)))
11.61
```

Does anyone have any experience with MIDI playback using these libraries, and if so, what might account for the playback to pause intermittently? Here is some more System information:

```
user> (-> (javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem/getSynthesizer) .getDeviceInfo bean)
{:version "Version 1.0", :vendor "Sun Microsystems", :name "Java Sound Synthesizer", :description \
"Software wavetable synthesizer and receiver", :class com.sun.media.sound.MixerSynth$MixerSynthInf\
o}

user> (map #(System/getProperty %) ["java.version" "java.vm.version" "os.name"])
("1.6.0_51" "20.51-b01-457" "Mac OS X")
```

Comment: Need more info: `(-> (javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem/getSynthesizer) .getDeviceInfo bean)` and `(map #(System/getProperty %) ["java.version" "java.vm.version"])`.

Comment: Right, should have asked for "os.version" too, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148898/java-midi-in-mac-osx-broken, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749172/why-java-midi-synth-on-mac-stop-playing-notes, and http://www.humatic.de/htools/mmj.htm

Comment: Ah yes, this describes the behavior I am experiencing exactly. My Mac OS X version is `10.8.4`, btw. I wonder if using Oracle's version of Java 7 would correct the problem?

Comment: I suspect it would. Latest version has the Gervill synth, which seems to be a vast improvement.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate. Answer is its an OS X Lion Java issue. Can use the Gervill synth in Java 6 or upgrade to Java 7.