# Control + W to exit system

Tags: java, keycode, system.exit

I am working on a game and here I want the end-user to press Ctrl + W to exit the system.

Here is the code that I've used:

```
int key = e.getKeyCode();
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL && key == KeyEvent.VK_W) System.exit(1);
```

... but it didn't seem to work

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, `key` (as an `int`) can only be one value at a time, so it'll never be both keys simultaneously...

Comment: So is there a way of using something like I had in my mind in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java-check if control key is being pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659801/java-check-if-control-key-is-being-pressed)

Comment: You need to OR your two KeyEvent constants together.

Comment: @Rich but I have another command which the end user presses W to move upwards

Comment: Ah alright... I used || instead of | thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
KeyStroke keyExit = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, KeyEvent.VK_W); 
Action performExit = new AbstractAction("Exit") {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
        //exit method
    }
};
```

try with this kind of example.

Comment: The code isn't seeming to work... Where you commented `//exit method` I typed `System.exit(1);`

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along the lines of:

```
int key = e.getKeyCode();
if(key == (KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL | KeyEvent.VK_W)) System.exit(1);
```

Though that's untested and is from memory.

Comment: But I have another control which uses W as a player moving up so if I press W the system will still exit

Comment: @Star do you see the difference with what you are requesting?

Comment: @Stultuske yes... here if I press **W** from the keyboard it will exit the system as well.

Comment: the | is an OR, so only one of the keys is enough to trigger it. but since Netbeans uses the CTRL+[] shortcuts in the menu, it should be possible. maybe check their code

Comment: I use Eclipse though as my JDK